# Is there a way to obtain pipeline activity run details for Azure Synapse from Log Analytics?

Tags: azure-log-analytics, azure-synapse, azure-diagnostics

I have set up a log analytics workspace and added it to the diagnostic settings on my Synapse workspace. However, I am unable to write a query that extracts pipeline activity information such as dataRead, rowsCopied, etc.
I have tried using
dataReadvar = parse_json(Output).dataRead to extract the JSON within SynapseIntegrationActivityRuns but it doesn’t seem to be able to find ‘Output’.

Answer (score -1):

Azure Data Factory and Azure Synapse Analytics have three groupings of activities: [data movement activities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview), [data transformation activities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data), and [control activities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-pipelines-activities#control-flow-activities). An activity can take zero or more input [datasets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-datasets-linked-services) and produce one or more output [datasets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-datasets-linked-services).

Check for the sample pipeline for how it is defined and its pipeline activities:

```
{
    "name": "PipelineName",
    "properties":
    {
        "description": "pipeline description",
        "activities":
        [
        ],
        "parameters": {
        },
        "concurrency": <your max pipeline concurrency>,
        "annotations": [
        ]
    }
}
```

Below is the JSON format for Top level structure for Execution Activities:

```
{
    "name": "Execution Activity Name",
    "description": "description",
    "type": "<ActivityType>",
    "typeProperties":
    {
    },
    "linkedServiceName": "MyLinkedService",
    "policy":
    {
    },
    "dependsOn":
    {
    }
}
```

Activity Policy:

```
{
    "name": "MyPipelineName",
    "properties": {
      "activities": [
        {
          "name": "MyCopyBlobtoSqlActivity",
          "type": "Copy",
          "typeProperties": {
            ...
          },
         "policy": {
            "timeout": "00:10:00",
            "retry": 1,
            "retryIntervalInSeconds": 60,
            "secureOutput": true
         }
        }
      ],
        "parameters": {
           ...
        }
    }
}
```

Here are few MS Docs as [Docs1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-pipelines-activities), [Docs2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-pipeline-execution-triggers) which are related to your scenario which can help.

Comment: Did this answer resolve your problem?